# how to open drawer from another screen component in react native with using another screen in props of contentcomponent

Tags: react-native

this is the screen from where we are calling the drawerscreen

```
        <View style={{top:25,marginLeft:10}}>
         <TouchableOpacity>
           <Icon color="#000000" name="menu"  onPress={() => navigation.navigate('DrawerOpen')}/>
         </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
```

this is the drawer screen from where i used in App.js

```
const MainDrawer = createDrawerNavigator({
   MainTabs : MainTabs,
   },{
  contentComponent:props =><Drawescreen {...props}/>
});
```

how can i call the drawer screen from anothe screen i used many terms to call the drawer 
1-toggle drawer
2-drawerOptions

but still its not working how to fix this ?

Comment: can you share your code in an expo snack, so that i can check there

Comment: https://snack.expo.io/r1TlFAdCr

Comment: just sharing the piece code

Comment: its not a working snack, so can you make it workble so that i can check

Comment: then i have to upload the full project

Comment: umm, dont share all code, better make dummy classes where i can check, and you shouldnt upload code. thats private

Comment: can u tell me the component which should i used or any example ? that how i can call the drawerscreen

Comment: cz i am calling the drawercomponent in Contentcomponent and storing the screen in props

Comment: try that once in expo snack

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for are NavigationActions. You need to dispatch action from ScreenTest screen in your case. Here is code:

```
 navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      headerRight: () => {
        const navigateAction = NavigationActions.navigate({
          routeName: "DrawerNavigation",
          action: DrawerActions.openDrawer()
        });

        return (
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={{ width: 50, height: 50, backgroundColor: "crimson" }}
            onPress={() => navigation.dispatch(navigateAction)}
          ></TouchableOpacity>
        );
      }
    })
```

It doesn't necessarily need to be in headerRight. Since your code is broken here is [dummy example](https://snack.expo.io/@kenodek/bd8657)

[And link to documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-actions.html)